# Structuremap loading assemblies from sub folders

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap, structuremap4

I have a service that uses application domains. A few legacy domains living in isolation and work supervised via a main process.

The main application and sub processes have different IOC containers.

With version 4.2.0.402 of structuremap I noticed that "AssembliesAndExecutablesFromPath" is loading all assemblies, even the binaries from sub process folder(s) - this is causing a bit of a nightmare.

I can hack it by using a "scanner.Exclude" but it just feels wrong having to hard code a folder name to exclude.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I did log an issue on the github repo https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/issues/619 but decided to work around it as per comment in post using reflection.